# MySQL JOIN and DELETE only first occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to delete 40 mln rows from MySQL table.

I have to find all rows with output -> "**STATIC OUTPUT**" 
then delete the row with above output and delete next row having the same host 
and service of above output **and** output value other than "**STATIC OUTPUT**".

Sample data:

columns **->** id, host, service, output

```
1,"127.0.0.1","service1","STATIC OUTPUT"
2,"127.0.0.2","service5","RANDOM OUTPUT X0"
3,"127.0.0.2","service5","STATIC OUTPUT"
4,"127.0.0.3","service1","RANDOM OUTPUT X1"
5,"127.0.0.3","service10","RANDOM OUTPUT X2"
6,"127.0.0.2","service5","RANDOM OUTPUT X3"
7,"127.0.0.1","service2","RANDOM OUTPUT X4"
8,"127.0.0.1","service1","RANDOM OUTPUT X5"
9,"127.0.0.2","service4","RANDOM OUTPUT X6"
10,"127.0.0.3","service10","RANDOM OUTPUT X7"
11,"127.0.0.1","service1","RANDOM OUTPUT X7"
12,"127.0.0.1","service1","RANDOM OUTPUT X8"
13,"127.0.0.1","service1","RANDOM OUTPUT X9"
14,"127.0.0.2","service5","RANDOM OUTPUT X10"
15,"127.0.0.1","service1","STATIC OUTPUT"
16,"127.0.0.1","service1","RANDOM OUTPUT X11"
17,"127.0.0.1","service1","RANDOM OUTPUT X12"    
...
```

Example: when we found

```
1,"127.0.0.1","service1","STATIC OUTPUT"
```

we should delete the row with id values 1 and 8,

```
8,"127.0.0.1","service1","RANDOM OUTPUT X5"
```

when we found

```
3,"127.0.0.2","service5","STATIC OUTPUT"
```

we should delete the row with id values 3 and 6,

```
6,"127.0.0.2","service5","RANDOM OUTPUT X3"
```

I wrote something like this (SELECT intead of DELETE statement because of test query),

```
SELECT * FROM data r1 INNER JOIN (SELECT id, host, service 
FROM data 
WHERE output = 'STATIC OUTPUT') r2 ON 
      r1.id>r2.id AND r1.service=r2.service 
      AND r1.host=r2.host 
      AND r1.output<>'STATIC OUTPUT' 
GROUP BY r1.host, r1.service
```

But I think that it is a wrong way.

MySQL 5.1.73

Comment: Do you have the option to restructure the table because it doesn't feel right to me the way you store and work with the data. You have a history of data there. Why don't you make the host/service unique?

Comment: I can not change the structure of the table. I am app/system administrator not app developer. The query should be used only once. We have a lot of unnedded data because of the system bug.

Comment: If you don't structure your database correctly, you will always have wrong data from time to time ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORRECTION

This should now do it!:

```
SELECT min(sp.id) as id FROM
(SELECT hs.id, hs.host, hs.service, hs.output, so.id as soid
FROM data hs
INNER JOIN
(SELECT id,host,service,output FROM data 
WHERE output = "STATIC OUTPUT") so
ON so.host = hs.host and so.service = hs.service
AND hs.id > so.id WHERE hs.output <> "STATIC OUTPUT") sp
group by host,service, soid
UNION 
SELECT id FROM data WHERE output = "STATIC OUTPUT";
```

Comment: Something is wrong. On a test table I got multiple records with the same host and service. Maybe I have not show enought data. The value output is diferent on each next row of the same host and service. I got all, not only first row after "STATIC OUTPUT" with th same host and service.

Comment: Can you provide some more test data?

Comment: I added 4 more rows. In your query I got 11-14 too.

Comment: Ok I've replicated the problem.  Looking at it now

Comment: @Dream Just posted correction.  Could you please try it and let me know if it works?

Comment: It works! Thank you Jonathan. It was abstract for me :) PS. What is the best way to use delete on the statement?

Comment: @Dream DELETE FROM data WHERE id in ( .... ).  Just one question before you do this, though.  Is it possible that there are multiple records with the same host, service and "STATIC OUTPUT"?  If so, this query only catches one non-static output; i.e. it will not catch the first one after every STATIC OUTPUT, if you understand what I mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153099/discussion-between-jonathan-willcock-and-dream).

Comment: Yes there are multiple records with the same host, service and "STATIC OUTPUT". I understand, I should use it iteratively. Is any fix to catch all?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the LIMIT statement to select the first occurrence.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

```
SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 1;
```

### Edit:

This sample will find you the Id to be erased

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v AS
    SELECT  r1.id as id1 , r2.id as id2 FROM data r1 
    INNER JOIN data r2 ON r1.host=r2.host AND r1.service = r2.service
    WHERE LOWER(r1.output) LIKE "static output" AND r1.id < r2.id;
```

```
    SELECT DISTINCT id1 FROM v
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT id2 FROM v;
```

#### Output:

id:  1  3  6  8

Comment: Limit is not useful here, just use the example I gave for the answer

Comment: Output (removed) should be: 1 3 6 8. Pairs -> 1,8 and 3,6. Before 2 there is not "STATIC OUTPUT" with the same ip and service.

Comment: Now using the view you can do it more easily (with the desired output)

Comment: The same problem as in Jonathan case.

Comment: Updated but could you describe with more details what's wrong and update your post with what you would like ?

Comment: It returns all next rows with the same host and service after value "STATIC OUTPUT". Not only the first. I have added 4 more rows to my sample data. After your query I got 11-14 unneded ids.